# Meta Stack Overflow reputation is not showing on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, reputation, area-51

In Area 51, I have followed the site http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts where, in the follow member list, my flair is also displayed, but as other members' flair is displayed with all their Stack Overflow's related account.

For your reference, I am connected with Stack Overflow, Area 51 and Meta Stack Overflow and in Area 51. Only my Stack Overflow and Area 51 reputation points are showing up, **`not showing up Meta Stack Overflow reputation`** (have a look at [Android Enthusiasts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts)). What is the reason behind not showing up reputation in Area 51? Is there any rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its only shown for associated accounts that have at least 200 reputation and you currently only have 189 on MSO.

Comment: @Georg on accepting your answer, my reputation become 201, still not showing !!

Comment: @Paresh: The reps are not synced immediately. There is some time lag.

Comment: @KennyTM i have refreshed many time and even logged out many time also. what is the lag-time ?

Comment: @Parest: At least a hour. The rep is sync only at regular interval between databases on the servers, whether you have logged out or refreshed do not matter.

Comment: @KennyTM ok...thanx for the answer

Comment: @Par It took almost 24 hours for all my rep to show on one of my proposals.

Comment: It's synced nightly.