# Reputation for linked accounts not showing in Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51, combined-flair

I've recently created an account at Area 51, to follow and commit to a proposal. In the [list of commited users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539?page=3&phase=commitment&committers=userreputation#tab-top) my "total rep" is showing only the Area 51 reputation, but not the Stack Overflow one (the only one I have >200). The commitment score for that proposal is also showing `18/100 committers with 200+ rep on any other site`, confirming I'm not included in the count.

Why is that happening? I looked at [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61789/177950) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52119/177950) and saw that most commonly it's either because of low rep (<200) or because of a delay in the database sync (I waited 3 days before asking here). Neither applies to my case. My accounts seem to be properly linked, at least my [discussion user](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/54808/mgibsonbr) shows all of them.

**Update:** as a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126869/177950) shows, that's probably a bug. Also, I'd like to point out that having <200 rep in Area 51 is not a problem, since many users (like [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/40552/hexa) and [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/5044/nelson-reis)) are in the same situation, but their flair looks fine (as can be seen [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/software-development-in-portuguese)).

Comment: Has there been any progress in resolving this issue? I seem to be having similar symptoms.

Comment: @GeneGolovchinsky No progress so far AFAIK, but some mods seem to be looking at it.

Comment: Thanks! I had no response to my similar question, other than the initial comment that it was probably a duplicate of your question.

Comment: Identical problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed now.

The Q&A sites recently dropped all support for our "old" (guid-based) method of keeping track of account across the network. This change wasn't properly handled by some parts of Area 51. However, all of the missing data has been backfilled, and it should work correctly going forward. Sorry about that.