# Why is my Area51 flair not updating?

Tags: bug, area-51, combined-flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation for linked accounts not showing in Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126466/reputation-for-linked-accounts-not-showing-in-area-51)

I linked my accounts a few days ago, and I am wondering why my Stack overflow account isn't showing up specifically in my Area51 flair when it meets the minimum 200 reputation requirement.

It shows up in my regular network flair image:

[image: Network flair]

but does not show up in my flair when I'm listed at Area51:

[image: Area51 flair]

Comment: Certainly seems related to the other question. In my case, I do have more than 200 rep in Area51 and in SO.