# Eeeeek! Why are there undead accounts in my Area 51 flair?

Tags: bug, area-51, deleted-accounts

1.5 months ago, I had some accounts removed and dissociated. My Area 51 "flair" still shows icons from one of the old accounts, though, and includes their reputation: .

[image]

It is not the case of [flair not updating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126466/reputation-for-linked-accounts-not-showing-in-area-51), as the reputation for other sites have been updated.

Comment: This is a question for http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: From their [FAQ](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/faq): "You should not ask questions about launched Stack Exchange sites or the operation of the Stack Exchange network (bugs, feature-requests, support, etc). Those questions belong on our network meta-discussion site. "

Comment: It's the Area 51 flair, which is not the usual one. There is the "area51-meta" tag for a reason.

Comment: Maybe, I find the FAQ ambiguous on that point. Still, it's definitely a Stack Exchange bug that removed accounts aren't really removed.

Comment: It's more than likely a caching issue (or glitch) with the accounts on Area 51's end. It's probably seeing the account is gone and just  not updating it for the Area 51 list or something. There have been much odder things happen with Area 51's flair before.

Comment: As for your last paragraph it's wrong. The accounts are removed and the 404 error page kind of proves this.. isn't it?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: In one sense it's removed, in one it isn't.

Comment: Dissociation is not a healthy way to deal with having accounts removed.  You might want to see somebody about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Area 51's logic for updating and caching associated account information has a bug: it does not properly handle

- account deletion
- account user id changes (e.g. after a merge)

These will be fixed. In the meantime, I've manually removed your old Gaming account from your Area 51 flair.

Comment: Just in time for the bounty.. coincidence? ;)

Comment: Is it fixed by now? :)

Comment: I sure hope so..

Comment: Well, did you fix it while still being a dev? ;)

Comment: Partially fixed: [correct on user flair](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f7duw.png), [phantom site on flair shown on proposals (e.g. committers)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F1vLG.png). (Rep/badge totals differ between the two, too.)